# h5ai (Windows & Nginx) doesn't show my files

Tags: php, nginx

I am trying to setup [h5ai](https://larsjung.de/h5ai/) on my windows computer using Nginx. i've managed to access the h5ai home page by this url: `http://localhost/_h5ai/public/index.php`.
And it shows this page:[image: h5ai index content]

I don't see any file from my computer here, as i know, i need to put them on the home root from nginx with the _h5ai folder containing all the h5ai stuff:
[image: Home root nginx]

I had some `chatgpt help` to install choco and zip package, also to write the options.json file. i also tried to strictly follow [h5ai](https://larsjung.de/h5ai/) installation guide. Please note `i am new to php, Nginx and h5ai`.

1st problem:

I cannot see the desired files (example: "folder" folder, image sent above).

#2nd problem:

I have tried to install Zip on my computer using choco on powershell, and it went sucessfully, i can execute "zip" from the windows command line and all, i even specified the file name on the h5ai `options.json`
file, but the h5ai site doesn't seems to be detecting it at all.

[image: Options.json code block]

I know this file is being read because i've set a hashed password and the h5ai site works with the new password.

Hypothesis to fix 1st problem: I probably should also download the shell command "du", i would've done that already but choco doesn't seems to have this package.

If necessary, this is my `nginx.conf` file:

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;


    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location /h5ai {
         root   /html/_h5ai/public/;
         index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

    }
}
```

Comment: What does your nginx server file look like? Usually it's present in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` (usually `default` unless you've renamed it) ?

Comment: Hey, i couldn't find this default folder anywhere, also i don't remember renaming any folder with this name, was i supposed to create it somewhere?

Comment: you might find a different file under `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` directory - let me know whats present in there